# Popups default focus on button - best practice

Tags: usability, accessibility, popup, keyboard-shortcuts, confirmation

Do we need to auto focus on any one of the buttons inside a popup? Since, some users prefer keyboard to interact with the application.

For example: Confirmation popups in destructive actions like *Delete*?

[image: Confirmation popup]

Any suggestion is really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: yes. Which element, though depends on the content.

Per [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#dialog_modal):

> If a dialog contains the final step in a process that is not easily
>   reversible, such as deleting data or completing a financial
>   transaction, it may be advisable to set focus on the least destructive
>   action, especially if undoing the action is difficult or impossible.
>   The Alert Dialog Pattern is often employed in such circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

In UI Design you have 3 modes of actions:

If you designing pop-up for destructive action, the order of buttons and their priority differs in relation to systems and design approaches.
In the screens below:

1. The priority of action
2. Example of good practise

[image]

[image]